# Evitar pregunta de desambiguación en Google Play (con que aplicación abrir)

Tags: android-studio, app, google-play, pwa

tengo mi pwa subida a google play, es una aplicación desarrollada en laravel y empaquetada en Android Studio, se instala y abre bien en el navegador en la mayoría de los celus, pero el problema que tengo es que en algunas marcas (samsung principalmente) aparece la pregunta de desambiguación para confirmar si abre con la app o con el navegador, intuitivamente el usuario elige abrir con la app y queda en error porque se debe seleccionar el navegador (Chrome, Internet de Samsung, etc).

[image: Pregunta de desambigución]

Aquí agrego el código de mi manifest del proyecto en android studio.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ar.com.amparosrl">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <meta-data
            android:name=".DEFAULT_URL"
            android:value="${defaultUrl}"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:value="${assetStatements}" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="${hostName}" ></data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Aquí va la dirección en google play
[App Amparo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ar.com.amparosrl)

No sé si existe la posibilidad de evitar esa pregunta y que directamente intente abrir en el navegador disponible, creo que necesito modificar mi manifest, les agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No hay forma de mejorar lo que quiero mejorar, lo que hago es un vínculo de la app y si puede evitará la pregunta de desambiguación pero no hay forma de obligar a buscar el navegador, aquí pego el detalle según developers de android:

Diferencia entre vínculos directos y vínculos de la app
Un vínculo directo es un filtro de intents que permite a los usuarios ingresar directamente una actividad específica de tu app para Android. Cuando haces clic en uno de estos vínculos, es posible que se abra un diálogo de desambiguación, que permite al usuario seleccionar una app entre varias (incluida la tuya) que pueden administrar la URL determinada. Por ejemplo, en la figura 1, se muestra el cuadro de diálogo de desambiguación después de que el usuario hace clic en un vínculo del mapa y le pregunta si desea abrirlo en Maps o Chrome.

Un Android App Link es un vínculo directo basado en la URL de tu sitio web que tiene la verificación de que pertenece a tu sitio web. Por lo tanto, cuando haces clic en uno de estos vínculos, se abre tu app de inmediato, si está instalada. El diálogo de desambiguación no aparece. Sin embargo, el usuario puede cambiar su preferencia para manejar este tipo de vínculos más adelante.